# H.264 video frame data conversion to UIImage

Tags: ios, video, streaming, h.264

I am wondering if anyone knows how to convert h.264 video frame data to a UIImage (without using FFMPEG). I believe this can be done with CoreVideo/CoreMedia/AVFoundation but need some guidance on
how.

Answer (score 0):

AVAssetImageGenerator class has these two methods for capturing video frames:

```
– copyCGImageAtTime:actualTime:error:
– generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:completionHandler:
```